# Making a CSS dropdown menu - can't find error

Tags: css

Trying to make a menu, very new to CSS.  I think the error is somewhere in

```
 .nav ul li:hover > ul li a { color: purple; min-width:150px;}
  .nav ul li:hover > ul li a:hover { color:pink;}
```

but I can't figure out what, and don't have the experience to figure out if it's elsewhere.  Everything else except the dropdown seems to work.

I have been using http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Dropdown-Menu-in-HTML-and-CSS as a reference.

Many thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html!>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <! css link goes here !>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
       background-color:orange}


  .nav ul ul {               /* the . in front on nav is critical! */
      display:none;
       }

  .nav ul li: hover > ul {
      display: block;
       }

  .nav ul {
       padding: 0 20px;
       border-radius: 10px;
       list-style: none;
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
       background: green}

  .nav ul li {
       float:left}

  .nav ul li a{ 
       padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
       display:block;
       color: red; /* heading text color */
       text-decoration: none;
       }

  .nav ul li:hover {
       background: orange; /* hover over menu and color changes */
        }

  .nav ul li:hover a {
       color:blue; /* hover over menu and text color changes */
       } 

  .nav ul li:hover > ul { margin:0px; padding:0px;}
  .nav ul li:hover > ul li { float:none; display:block;}
  .nav ul li:hover > ul li a { color: purple; min-width:150px;}
  .nav ul li:hover > ul li a:hover { color:pink;}

  .nav ul li { position:relative; }
  .nav ul li ul { position: absolute; top:30px; left:0px; }

  }

  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="nav">
       <ul> 
            <li><a href="media">Media</a></li>  
            <li><a href="previous expeditions">Previous Expeditions</a> 

                 <ul> 
                      <li><a href="morocco">Morocco</a></li>
                      <li><a href="iceland">Iceland</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tajikistan">Tajikistan</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="sponsors">Sponsors</a></li>
        </ul>



  </div>  <! end of nav div!>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code as such.

Just see this line:

```
.nav ul li: hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Did you notice the whitespace before `hover`. Just remove that and it will work. Whenever you write a selector of this sort, there should be not whitespace between the `:` and pseudo-selector.

After the change:

```
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

See the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/xLxLA/).

Comment: Thank you very much, got it sorted thanks to both of your help!

Answer (score 2):

Update following `CSS`. and it will show dropdown.

```
  .nav ul li:hover > ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; display:block;}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kishori/P3MwJ/)

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you very much, got it sorted thanks to both of your help!